# How do you make a:visited bold in XHTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
a:visited
{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

EDIT: Removed the space after the ":", but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the space after the `a:`

Comment: Can you post the rest of the CSS? You maybe have a stronger rule elsewhere that is overriding this.

Comment: This is the whole CSS, there is no other style in the either the CSS or the HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah — I believe this won’t work in recent browsers, because they disabled most styles for visited links to prevent websites from detecting the user’s web browsing history:

- http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

For example, in Chrome 15, the visited link on this fiddle has a different colour, but is not bold:

- http://jsfiddle.net/XbVpe/

Looks like Firefox added this in version 4:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002994/how-can-i-still-style-visited-links-after-new-security-changes-implemented-in-br

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the cause of the problem. I tried it in IE6, and it did work.

Comment: @ikoddn: you’re very welcome, I think this has caught a lot of people out. If you’re happy this is the right answer, you could hit the tick mark next to it to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the space:

```
a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The reason it didn't work before is because space is a descendent selector: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

> A descendant selector is made up of two or more selectors separated
>   by white space. A descendant selector of the form "A B" matches when
>   an element B is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

Comment: @ikoddn — All else being equal, it does work. You might have other code overriding it, but obviously we can't see that.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of CSS selector need to be attached to what it's referring to, such as:
`a:visited`